# Translate geometry of object so all subsequent transforms include the original translation

Tags: scenekit, vuforia

Within SceneKit I create a box and want to translate it along the y-axis, but I want all transforms to that box's node (translation, rotation, scaling) to not impact the original translation of the geometry. How can I accomplish this using SCNNode?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607482/recalculate-scnnode-geometry-based-on-transformation/57255801#57255801

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Double wrap the geometry

It is fairly simple to double wrap an object using an `SCNNode`->`SCNNode`->`SCNGeometry`.

```
let planeBox = SCNBox(width: 50.0, height: 50.0, length: 1.0, chamferRadius: 0.0)
planeBox.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)

let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeBox)
planeNode = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0, 50.0, 0.0)

let wrappingNode = SCNNode()
wrappingNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(wrappingNode)
```

Then all subsequent updates to the wrappingNode will be isolated from the original translation.

[image: SCNBox translated along y-axis]

Comment: Later I discovered SCNPlane(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)